# Processing modeler to update table

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Not sure if I'm missing something very basic or not, but I have 6 or 7 shapefile vector layers in a dozen or so models that I need to update a single field with a rather simple formula.  I could spend the time to simply edit each layer and update the field, but I was hoping to use the processing modeler to take advantage of batch processing.  My trouble is that I'm not understanding how to use the modeler to update existing layers - I've used it several times to create a new layer, but not update any existing ones.  I assume I'm just missing a piece of the puzzle?...

An example is that I have a field called "MNCPL_ID" which I want to update with: `lpad(  "STREETID" ,4,0)  ||   lpad(  "SEGMNTID" ,3,0)  ||   lpad( @row_number,3,0)` - easily done layer by layer with the field calculator, but how can I automate the process?
(Bonus points if you have a suggestion to make the last 3 numbers sequential for each "STREETID" instead of using @row_number)

*Not familiar with python scripts / still learning.

Comment: The processing toolbox has a field calculator tool, but it creates a new layer instead of updating the existing layer.

Comment: Thanks - but yeah, that's exactly my dilemma - I'd like to use it to update the layer that's selected as the input rather than create a new one.

Comment: @CEL-ma - You will need to use a script to update existing layers. The modeler typically creates temporary (or a final) output for most available tools.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was afraid of.  I don't have any experience with scripts yet... not even really sure where to begin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ***Networks*** plugin for QGIS has a tool to create or update an existing field, which can be used in a model or run in batch processing.

[image]
[image]

In the following example, the model updates the "azimuth" field with a formula. **A temporary or final layer is not created**, the existing one is simply updated.

[image]

Comment: The problem is: Can you run that algorithm in a model to update a layer instead of create a new one?

Comment: Yes to everything: it can be used in a model and allows you to create new fields or update existing ones.

Comment: Tried this out and it works perfectly for what I wanted! thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot select the "field" manually in the model builder. Why do you have to write manually "azimuth"?

Comment: @simone100 The plug-in allows you to select an existing field from the 'Field' drop-down list to update it, or to enter the name of a new field to be created (by additionally filling in the 'Size', 'Type' and 'Precision' options).

Comment: yes, now I see.